# Fonts showing as squares in Libre office

Tags: fonts

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed new fonts to Ubuntu which I was previously using on Windows. The English fonts works fine. However, all fonts in Arabic show as squares when I use them. The system Arabic fonts are rendering normally. All my fonts are of .ttf type.

I attached a photo to describe the situation. The first line shows that English fonts renders normally as well as native Arabic fonts as in the second line. However the installed Arabic fonts don't as in the last line.

[image: This is a description of the issue]

Comment: What is the exact name of the font used in the last line?

Comment: As shown on the image itself, ACS Topazz. However, I have many others and non of them worked.

Comment: I suggest you install "GNOME Character Map" (`sudo apt install gucharmap`) and test your "ACS Topazz" font with it.  Please, check the option "Show only glyphs from this font" in the View menu. Normally Libre Office should replace glyphs with another font that supports the specific character.

Comment: With `gucharmap`, first uncheck the option "Show only glyphs from this font". Then, once you find your glyph (select first Arabic from the Script list at the left for quick access), right click on the glyph (=character) to see which font is being used for displaying it. If it is not in the selected font, it will show you a font that supports your glyph. (Note that, it doesn't seem to give you a list of **all** the fonts that contain your glyph.)

Comment: It would be good to add all specific information in your question (use "edit"), including the names of the fonts you demonstrated do work.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to install the specific font of specific language  i.e: You will have to download Arabic version of the font. I have the link [here](https://brushez.com/free_download/Ijqzg/40154) 
[image: screenshot of libreoffice]

Comment: The OP already has installed the named font. However the font displays squares instead of the appropriate glyph. Did you try to install the font yourself?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I have installed the font and verified it that it works. I do not answer the questions simply without testing them. I respect your expertise but that does not mean that you have the freedom to disregard other's answer. I would like to know if you have tried to answer the question. Finally, just downvoting answers because you can do so, is not a great thing.

Comment: I did also install the font (I do not remember if it was the same download location.) But, it behaved exactly as the OP indicated; displaying squares. And no useful glyph seemed to be displayed in `gucharmap` test. I am not a font expert. But the font is very very old (~25 years or more). So, my current opinion is that the font does not work in Ubuntu.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I think you are right. It appears that the fonts themself do not work in ubuntu. I tried newer fonts in arabic and they worked.